# Find similar strings in T-SQL table

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I'm working on number plate recognition project. After number plate is recognized it is stored in MS SQL database. We have two cameras, and we get two images of one car, from front and from behind. Sometimes the recognizer recognize the number plate incorrectly from one of image. For example, the car with number plate 'AA1111' from first camera is recognized as 'AA111' and from second as 'AA1111'.

In my SQL table I have such records:

| id | NumberPlate | Confidence | CreatedAtTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA1111 | 100 | 13:44:00 |
| 2 | AA111 | 75 | 13:44:10 |
| 3 | BB2222 | 100 | 14:00:00 |
| 4 | AA11 | 35 | 13:44:12 |

From every record in example table we create an incident in a client app. But this is incorrect because the plates 'AA11' and 'AA111' is the same plate as 'AA1111'.

My goal is to create incident in client app only for unique number, in my example it should be: 'AA1111' and 'BB2222'

Have you any ideas how to perform this in MS SQL?

The database is hosted in Azure SQL Server

UPD:
I've write the SQL, but stuck with recursion limitation, may you hav some advice?

```sql
CREATE TABLE Plates(
  id INT not null,
  plate NVARCHAR(10),
  CreatedAtTime NVARCHAR(20),
  Confidence DECIMAL(18,5)
  )

INSERT INTO Plates
VALUES
(1,'LK2873','13:00:00',100),
(2,'LK287','13:00:10',70),
(3,'LK287','13:00:12',65),
(4,'AZ4875','14:00:00',100),
(5,'TR3345','14:15:32',100),
(6,'TR33','14:15:36',45),
(7,'TR334','14:15:40',70),
(8,'AA76','14:12:36',100),
(9,'DF324','14:13:00',100),
(9,'LK28','13:00:09',64)



;WITH tmp(plate,lvl,snd,ln)  as(
    SELECT Plate,1 lvl,soundex(Plate),LEN(Plate) FROM Plates 
        WHERE LEN(Plate)=(SELECT max(LEN(Plate)) FROM Plates)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tb.plate, lvl+1,SOUNDEX(tb.Plate),LEN(tb.Plate)
        FROM Plates tb
        INNER JOIn tmp  t ON tb.Plate =LEFT(tb.plate,LEN(t.plate))

)
SELECT * FROM tmp
```

Comment: *"The database is hosted in Azure SQL Server"* So is it *actually* an Azure SQL Database, or an Azure Managed Instance (or perhaps even Azure Synapse)?

Comment: This is Azure SQL Database

Comment: Hi @SBarkovskis. Is not more easy way use a combobox in app, for example, and fill with correct values, in this case 'AA1111';'BB1111'; etc

Comment: "But this is incorrect because the plates 'AA11' and 'AA111' is the same plate as 'AA1111'." How do you know that, what if AA11 is AA1112 ?

Comment: No its no, because there is no availability to interact with incident record. User can only see all incidents. All is working in automated way

Comment: Because of CreatedAtTime, there is no records with AA1112 at his time. You can see that all records is created in ~15 sec interval

Comment: Should your algoritm consider AA171 and AA111 same or not? Is number format always same (CCNNNN)? How precise is character recognition - how often does your camera read UV1I1 instead of UY111?

Comment: Since the number plate can be foreign, the CCNNNN not always true. In most cases only the last numbers are not recognized. That because the wrong angle of vehicle on image. For example a car is making turn and get fixed

Answer (score 0):

Think there is a lot of info needed to understand the full requirement.
But assuming you do a lookup with the value on the table for anything existing and then insert.

Maybe something like this:

and 'AA11' representing the new value coming in.

`WHERE 'AA11' = SUBSTRING(NumberPlate,1,LEN('AA11'))`

thus would try and validate against anything with the same pattern up to its own length. so if nothing matches, it would be the first. if it matches, there is another with the same or more characters.